# Having two python paths

Tags: pythonpath

When running

> python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;
>   print(get_python_lib())"

I see that the lib is:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages

BUT

when installing some software, it puts python packages under:

> /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/

When running the python code above that checks the version on each of the "python" files I see when I press "Tab" on the shell - all give the same python path.

I also tried to set the python path to the second - it didn't help. I used:

> export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/

Is there any good explanation for a package to be installed in the second one?
Is there any way I can define python to look at the other path too (so it'll search for both for packages), if no good solution for the prev question?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding both paths to sys.path

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: I tried: sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/'), but when exiting python and getting in back it does not appear, as if changes were not changed. ??